# Call netsh command using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to execute a netsh command from my php application using shell_exec. I get the following error:

The following command was not found: "interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.44.133 255.255.255.0 192.168.44.1".

My code is as follows:

```
    // Set the IP settings using netsh.
    echo shell_exec('netsh "interface ip set address name=\"Local Area Connection\" static ' . 
                    $strIPAddress . ' ' . 
                    $strSubnetMask . ' ' .
                    $strDefaultGateway . '"');
```

It is worth mentioning that I can execute other applications using shell_exec so it doesn't seem to be anything to do with my php.ini settings.

I am thinking it might be a permissions thing as the exact same command works when executing it in netsh, i.e. it changes the ip address and doesn't error.

I have also tried specifying the location of the netsh.exe and running it like that.

Please any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You have an extra double-quote before the `interface` keyword.

Comment: Arghhh! Thank you so much, how stupid of me! :-)